# PHP: http_get undefined reference. Ubuntu Karmic Koala

Tags: php, http-get

I am trying to use the http_get function. But I get a undefined reference error. I understands that this means the function can not be found. However I do no know how to fix this? Could somebody help?

Cheers

Comment: it probably means that you don't have `pecl_http` extension installed: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O.k so I sorted it out.

I used pecl:

```
user@user:~$ sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

Unfortunately this gave me an error which wanted me to install libcurl. Thus I installed it with:

```
user@user:~$ sudo aptitude install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

After that I tried pecl again:

```
user@user:~$ sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

It work, but I had to add:

```
extension=http.so
```

in my php.ini file.

After all those steps it worked.
To me it seems that everybody knows that this is what you should do to fix it. It stumps me that nobody has actually documented it.

Comment: I did all of these but I'm still having the same error come up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the curl_ methods to do the same thing

Comment: What is the difference between the normal http methods and the curl methods?